# Wordpress read more in loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

I'm new to wordpress and I have look around on this site and tested other suggestion but still the same problem " How to add the read more in my loop?". This is my loop that i'm using and is working fine, but I can't get the read more link in my loop. I have try other option but they only give me more problems with my website so I would like to stick to this code that i'm using and only add the read more link to it.

```
              <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

              <?php if ( in_category('11') ): ?>

                <?php else: ?>


                <?php endif; ?>


                  <h5><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>

                    <div class="meta"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> <?php comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »'); ?></div>

                  <div class="content"><p><?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 255);?></p></div>

          <?php endwhile;?>
```

Hope someone could help me out here with the "read more" link thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by adding

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) 
{
return 15;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );

function new_excerpt_more( $more ) 
{
return '... <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">read more</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

to the `functions.php` file and then replace

```
<?php echo substr(strip_tags($post->post_content), 0, 255);?>
```

with

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

You can change `15` a different value to increase the number of words shown.

Comment: You are my Hero. Because everybody talks about adding the excerpt in the loop, but nobody mention that you also have to add above code in the function.php, thanks you Howlin!!!

Comment: No problem, if it helped you answer yours question, feel free to mark it as correct so others who have a problem like yours will know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually generated by the_excerpt I believe.  Take a look a this link below.  You basically have to just insert the excerpt code where you would like readers to "read more" etc.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt